# Corrupted data read from mounted obb file on Nexus devices

Tags: android, corruption

We have a cross platform mobile app that uses a native **C** library to read some data (among other things).  On Android the data is in a obb file that we get using the Expansion APK mechanism.  This has been working very well for us.  However, we've found that on the 2nd generation (2013) Nexus 7 table and on Nexus 5 phones, we are reading some data from the obb that is corrupted.  The actual obb file is not corrupted, but what we read from it is.

The best example I have is with WebView reading an HTML file from the mounted obb.  The first part of the HTML will be fine and then there is gibberish in the second part.  Interestingly, the gibberish is recognizable as binary data from elsewhere in the obb.  It is almost like the Android code that reads the obb is getting the block mapping wrong.

I've narrowed it down to being triggered by some **C** code that reads objects out of the obb.  If I comment this out, the HTML will be fine when I later access it.  Now it is possible there are bugs in the **C** code, but this library has been used on two other platforms without issues.  It also works just fine on a first generation Nexus 7 and on other non-Nexus devices.

So does anyone have any thoughts about what this could be?  It seems to happen with both Android 4.3.x and Android 4.4.x on these Nexus devices.  What could be different hardware-wise that could cause this corruption?  I assume things like the **C** library come with Android and aren't built into the firmware somehow?

Comment: I've gotten no responses to this query.  I have since proved almost surely that this is a bug in mounted obb file on the second gen Nexus.  I can narrow it down to a simple fread of 2 bytes in the JNI that causes corruption.  What is the best way to report this to the Android developers?  Ideally I'd like a dialog with them to ask about possible work arounds.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related or not, but in my situation, I'm dragging a zip file off the SD card (which my application created) and in some situations, the file becomes corrupt in the process of dragging it off the SD card. It's not corrupt on the device as I can read is fine with the android Zip APIs, it's just when I drag it off the device. If I transfer it to a network share via a file manager app, everything is fine and un-corrupted. Certainly seems like a device issue somewhere! By the way, I'm using a nexus 7 4.4.4.

Comment: I've come across the same problem with a game made with cocos2d-x, when mounting an OBB file, the app will crash randomly on ressource loadings. Has anyone been able to overcome this bug ?

Comment: I have the exact same symptoms on Nexus 5 and HTC One M8 devices...the OBB MD5 checksum is fine....it works fine on almost all devices except these two....but on those two models, some of the files read from the OBB come back corrupt. Did you get anywhere with this or did you decide to stop using the official OBB format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, randomly corrupted assets when reading from the OBB  in a native C library using stdio functions. Segments of 128 bytes were consistently corrupted in the mounted OBB. Any changes in the data would shift the byte segment, resulting in a different asset being corrupted. This was only a problem for phones running O/S v.4.4.x(KitKat) and v.5.x.x(Lollipop), phones running 6.x.x(Marshmallow) and later are unaffected as far as I know.

To circumvent this, rather than mounting the .obb, I ended up using the alternate .zip method as outlined here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html.

I simply packed the data into a .zip with 0 compression(store), renamed to .obb, uploaded it to google play. When the user first starts the app, I extract the file to external storage using the APK Expansion Zip Library and then read the files directly rather than via mounting. This results in the app being twice the size on the phone, but it's preferable to being completely broken on some systems due to corrupted data.

Comment: Yes, we switched over to use the Expansion APK mechanism as well.

Comment: Just to throw my two cents into this, I experienced the same issue in production and didn't have the option of expanding the .obb (would cause 1gb storage vs 500mb) ending up pretty stumped.
Magically this was resolved by re-packaging the .obb with jobb with no changes to parameters (contents changed)
Seems like it could just be an intermittent jobb bug? or mounting bug with certain obb layouts.

My advice to anyone who experiences this is to hunt down a device where this occurs (in my case Nexus 5 with 4.4.X) and just rebuild the obb hoping for it to fix itself...